# Make ListBox items have a different value than item text

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a `ListBox` full of items. Although, each item should have a different value.
So when the user selects an item and presses a button, a method will be called which will use the value the select item has.

I don't want to reveal the item values to the user.

**EDIT:** This is not for ASP.NET, it's for a Windows Forms application. I just thought the HTML example would be easy to read.

I have the inspiration from HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Value1" /> Male
<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Value2" /> Female
</form>
```

This also allows me to use different values than what the user sees.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can choose what do display using the DisplayMember of the ListBox.

```
List<SomeData> data = new List<SomeData>();
data.Add(new SomeData() { Value = 1, Text= "Some Text"});
data.Add(new SomeData() { Value = 2, Text = "Some Other Text"});
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
listBox1.DataSource = data;
```

When the user selects an item, you can read the value (or any other property) from the selected object:

```
int value = (listBox1.SelectedItem as SomeData).Value;
```

Update: note that DisplayMember works only with properties, not with fields, so you need to alter your class a bit:

```
public class SomeData
{
    public string Value { get; set; };
    public string Text { get; set; };
}
```

Comment: When using DisplayMember, it makes more sense to set ValueMember="Value" and then read SelectedValue

Comment: @Henk: +1, I agree, I just wanted to point out that you can get access to the full object, not only "pre-assigned" properties.

Comment: Hi, your code seems to work, thanks. There is a minor error though. It  will not display the item Text in the listbox. It writes Namespace.SomeData....

The value part works perfectly though, thanks!

Comment: @caspert; glad it helped. The Text property was just an example, you can of course use any suitable property from the objects to use in your list, just set DisplayMember to the name of the property to show.

Comment: I tried setting it to = Text; as it is the property it should show the clients in the listbox. Although it still writes Namespace.SomeData in the listbox instead.

Comment: What does the object that you add to the list look like (you can update your question with a code sample)?

Comment: Ah, didn't thought of that. It all works perfectly now. Thanks

Comment: @FredrikMörk where do you place the code in the form_load ?

Comment: Its work!!!. By the way, how we can do storing selected status for item selected (also multiple item can be selected) into class ?. perhaps like this new SomeData(){Value = 1, Text = "One", Selected = true} and many more... SomeData(){Value = 2, Text = "Two", Selected = false} ...

Answer (score 3):

items have a property called 'Tag', which you can use to store any information you want (hidden from the user)

```
ListViewItem myItem = new ListViewItem();
myItem.Text = "Users see this";
myItem.Tag = "Users don't see this";
```

(or set the appropriate properties in the property explorer)

Comment: Could you show an example? each item needs their own individual value

Comment: Question is about `ListBox`. AFAIK, `ListViewItem` only would be used inside a `ListView`. Would it work to use `ListViewItem` in a `ListBox`?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [the 1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867514/make-listbox-items-have-a-different-value-than-item-text/867542#867542), the use of `DisplayMember` works whether you are using asp.net or winforms.

And to comment a bit more, it also works if you are using the rather old fashion `Items.add` way of adding items to a `ListBox`.

Just for fun, here is a simple demo of what you need (just create a new form and drop on it a ListBox and a Label):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", LastName, FirstName);
        }
    }

    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);                        
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "LastName";            
        listBox1.DataSource = GetCustomers();
        //listBox1.Items.AddRange(GetCustomers().ToArray());            
    }

    private IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer() { FirstName = "Gustav", LastName = "MAHLER" },
            new Customer() { FirstName = "Johann Sebastian", LastName = "BACH" }
        };
    }

    private void lb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }        
}
```

Enjoy

PS: [@2nd post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867514/make-listbox-items-have-a-different-value-than-item-text/867524#867524) `Tag` is not available to `ListBox`: because it accepts an array of `object`, not a specific item container like `ListView`... but you don't need any in your case. `Tag` is useful when you want to carry additional data along with a specific `TreeViewItem` or `ListViewItem` for example. 
By the way, `Tag` is defined at the `Control` level and so exists for `Button`, `Label`, and so on... but for my part I think it is rather a bad idea to store business data in it (untyped, UI coupled...) apart from the `ListView` and `TreeView` cases for which it is rather convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
foreach(var item in *Your Source List*)
        {
            ListItem dataItem =  new ListItem();
            dataItem.Text = "value to show";
            dataItem.Value = *another value you want*;
            listBox.Items.Add(dataItem);
        }
```

Comment: `ListItem` class is part of `WebControls`, not part of `Windows Forms`, as the question requests.

Answer (score -1):

Easy!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        llenaListBox(ListBox1, 0, 10);
    }

    private void llenaListBox(ListBox PoListBox, int PiMinimo, int PiMaximo)
    {
        int Li;
        for (Li = PiMinimo; Li <= PiMaximo; Li++)
        {
            ListItem obj = new ListItem();
            obj.Text  = Li.ToString();
            obj.Value = Li.ToString();
            PoListBox.Items.Add(obj);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `ListItem` class is part of `WebControls`, not part of `Windows Forms`, as the question requests.