# How to sum a value with string on listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I just want to know how to get the total value.

here's an example inside the listbox:

```
Soda - 30
Food - 50
```

How can I sum the 30 and 50 and show it on a textbox? Please help.
My code for adding to listbox is:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("btnSoda.text");
```

and my code for button that will get the total value:

```
int i = 0, result = 0;
while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
{           
    result += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i++]);
}

textboxtotal.Text = Convert.ToString((double)result)
```

after I run the program and click on getTotal Value it shows an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Comment: Create an Item class which has two properties, for example: ItemName, and ItemPrice, and after that you can iterate through the listbox items and sum the price values.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867514/make-listbox-items-have-a-different-value-than-item-text). You have to create key value pair. Then you can add the same by using values.

Comment: can you give me an example in code form? im sorry im just a newbie who is willing to learn. Thank you very much :) @C1sc0

Comment: @Lifewithsun KeyValue pair is a bad choice. Use a own class instead (see C1sc0) because it's the cleaner way and better to read.

Comment: Are you using WPF, winforms or something else?

Comment: im using winforms in VisualStudio 2015. can you give me an example of create a class code and iterate it to listbox? thank you very much for helping @MightyBadaboom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Split()` and `Sum()`:

```
var sum = listBox1.Items
         .OfType<string>()
         .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]))
         .Sum();
```

and then:

```
lbltotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Also, you can change your code a little and it should work:

```
while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
{           
    result += Convert.ToInt32(((string)listBox1.Items[i++]).Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]);
}
```

Comment: If he is a beginner, definitely he will get confused with this piece of code, But nice and quick, I hope you should take the first index instead for second, that means  `s.Split(..)[2]` should be  `s.Split(..)[1]`

Comment: can i ask where will i put this codes? thank you for answering :)

Comment: @Mark, simply replace your code with `while`loop by this

Comment: @RomaDoskoch thank you very much it works! i've accept your answer! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an own class for your items. Something like

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public Item(string name, int price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
listBox1.Items.Add("btnSoda.text");
```

you have to write

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("btnSoda.text");
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string name = parts[0];
    int price = int.Parse(parts[1]);
    Item item = new Item(name, price);
    items.Add(item);
}

comboBox1.DataSource = items;
```

With this piece of code you are reading your file and creating the `Item` items you want to show in your `ComboBox`. The advantage is that you have specific items with the properties you need and not a `string` which you have to interpret each time you want to do something with it.

Don't forget to set the `DisplayMember` property too `name` of your combobox. Otherwise you would not see the names of the items in your `ComboBox`.

After that you can use

```
int sum = comboBox1.Items
                   .OfType<Item>()
                   .Sum(x => x.Price);

label1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

to sum the prices.

Maybe it seems a bit more complicated then the other answer but it's the cleaner way.

**Some advantages**

- you will find out about errors in your textfile when you init your `ComboBox` and not when calculating the sum
- you don't have to interpret your items each time you want to do something with 'em because you already did that at the start
- easier to understand and read: no magic strings or numbers