# Adding a value to a listbox item. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a list box with my desired information inside it. However I need a number to be sent when the user selects on a specific row.

ListBox data:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

For example when I select Test1 in my list my I need to return the integer 2. I am asking if there is anyway I can assign the number 2 to be associated with `"Test2"`

```
listbox.Items.Add("Name displayed on list", value);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make ListBox items have a different value than item text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867514/make-listbox-items-have-a-different-value-than-item-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, ListBox Items are of type `object` and you can assign any object to them, so build a class like this:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Value {get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return Name;
    }
}
```

Now you can add ListBox Items like this:

```
listbox.Items.Add(new ListItem { Name = "Test1", Value = 2});
```

When a ListBox Item is Selected you can get its value like:

```
var value = ((ListItem)listbox.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Note that as ListBox Uses its Items `.ToString()` method to create Texts to show so you have to override it's `ToString()` method like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name;
}
```

Otherwise it will show the name of the class instead of your desired value.

Comment: This is one of those cases when the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the ListBox control can be quite useful. Instead of overriding `ToString()`, you could set `listbox.DisplayMember = "Name";` `listbox.ValueMember = "Value";`. Same result for the *visual* part, but you also have each object `Value` directly available, through the [SelectedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue) property.

Comment: Since there's a class involved, this class could also have a Property used to present the `ListBox.Items` text, completely different from the original text (a method used in a multilanguage environment, for example).

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, you could specify `DataSource` of your `listBox`, then you could use conviniently `SelectedValue` of `ListBox` class. But before you have to also specify `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` of a list box.

The most convinient in my opinion will be adding `Tuple<string, int>` objects to your list box and settings `ValueMember` to `"Item2"` and `DisplayMember` to `"Item1"`, as `Item1` willb e our string `Test1` and `Item2` will be integer value.

Code example:

```
  listBox1.ValueMember = "Item2";
  listBox1.DisplayMember = "Item1";
  listBox1.DataSource = new Tuple<string, int>[] {
    new Tuple<string, int>("Test1", 1),
    new Tuple<string, int>("Test2", 2)
  };
```

Now, in code you can just use `listBox1.SelectedValue` to access integer value of selected item.

Comment: Is get selected multiple item too ?