# Listbox Calculator

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, calculator

Hello everyone i need your help. Im just new to C# and i am creating a Program. i want this program to calculate the total amount of the priced items inside the listbox and Calculate the change with the amount given.. how i can put a value on my items so when i add it to my listbox it can be calculated?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V3jv.jpg

As you can see in the picture the items listed are Brownies and French Fries the total amount of brownies in the listbox is x5 which means 5 pieces and French Fries is x10 which is 10 orders so the total amount should be 375.00 and the change is 325.00

Comment: Do you have access to the listbox code? Are you supposed to be filling in missing code for this app?

Comment: @TejasPendse Yes i have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions* in order to *match* `number` of items and their `price`;
in order to query `ListBox.Items` we can use *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string pattern = 
    @"(?:\s+x(?<number>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\s*=\s*)?(?<price>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\s*$";

  var total = myListBox
    .Items
    .OfType<Object>()
    .Where(item => item != null)
    .Select(item => Regex.Match(item.ToString(), pattern))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .Select(match => new {
      number = string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["number"].Value)
        ? 1m  // if number is not specified we have 1 item
        : decimal.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value),
      price = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["price"].Value)
    })
    .Sum(item => item.price * item.number);
```

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/218102

Comment: thank you for the answer i will study about the code you give and Linq

Answer (score 0):

A `ListBox` might not be ideal for what you're trying to do because a `ListBoxItem` generally just stores one value. If you insist on using it, I recommend you store the price in the `ValueMember` and the text in the `DisplayMember` if you can. You can look up how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867542/7759395).

If however you want to proceed with that approach then make sure you can reliably use the last 5 chars in your string as the "Price".

You can iterate through every item in a `Listbox` and add the value of every `ListBoxItem` in a variable like so:

```
double total;
foreach(ListBoxItem i in ListboxName)
{
    total += Convert.ToDouble(i.Substring(i.Length-5));
}
```

It is then a simple matter of posting `total`.

Comment: i used listbox because i dont have that much knowledge on C# yet but if there's other easier options ill use it and thanks for the answer ill try that